# 400 HTTP error when sending form data type request

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rest, spring-security, multipartform-data

Hello Guys I'm sending a form data type request from (angular CLI 11) front-end to (spring boot) back end. In this request I want to send an image with some details.

Anyway I get 400 error when I send my request

- Front end service class relevent method

```
Send( file: File, description: string, feeling: string): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    const body: FormData = new FormData();
    body.append('file', file);
    body.append('description', description);
    body.append('feeling', feeling);
    return this.http.post<HttpResponse<any>>(environment.baseUrl + '/api/v1/launches', body, {
      observe: 'response'
    });
  }
```

- Back end relevant post method

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping(
            produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE
    )
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> save( @ModelAttribute LaunchBody body) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("body");

        try {
            System.out.println(body.getFile().getContentType());
            fileService.save(body.getFile());
            return new ResponseEntity<>("OK :)", HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Something went wrong !!", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

- CORS Filter

```
@Component
public class CORSFilter extends HttpFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTION");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-type,Origin,Authorization");
        super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    }
}
```

Comment: check your input syntax format, is springboot services in cross domain?

Comment: @CommonMan did you mean about CORS filter? I've included it above. I've a suspect  about *Access-Control-Allow-Headers*

Comment: First check your input syntax and input load is in correct format. CORS - if it's cross domain flag is available? which means, your spring boot services will be in a different server than your front end deployed. Also, check if the spring boot is allowing input from you or just within it's local limits.

Comment: @CommonMan you were correct my input format was wrong. I added my fault to the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Finally I discovered the answer. The prob was an error occurring when I creating the form data body :/ In there I've set a wrong value to the file element. In component.ts,

```
this.file = event.target.files;
```

this was the error this should be corrected to

```
this.file = event.target.files[0];
```